# Help: Issue with attaching multiple attachment controls in PowerApp form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, infopath, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am trying to migrate InfoPath forms library to a PowerApp form in SharePoint list. InfoPath forms library have xml files saved in SharePoint which contains many attachments linked to separate fields. But when i am checking in PowerApps then in PowerApps only way to attach files is using attachment control from an Edit Form of a list which will attach all files from a single place. Is it possible to have multiple attachment controls in a form to attach files and store them in backend SharePoint list? Please help as i am new to PowerApps development.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, within PowerApps, we could only **add single one Attachments control** within the Edit form. In addition, the Upload functionality of Attachments control only work in Edit form.

If you want to add multiple Attachments Data cards within your Edit form, and submit attachment files to your SP list, I afraid that there is no way to achieve your needs in PowerApps currently.

Actually, if you want to **upload multiple files to one record of your SP list as attachments**, you could add/upload multiple files within the single one Attachments control.

[image]

More details about the usage of Attachments control in PowerApps, please check the following blog:

- **https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/add-attachments-to-sharepoint-lists/**

More details about Attachments control, please check the following article:

- **https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/controls/control-attachments**

Comment: Thanks @EchoDu_MSFT for your response. I believe then my requirement is not possible with PowerApps. I tried using multiple attachment controls in new form by copying attachment data card, but there seems to be no way to display documents in edit form in respective sections as they are getting stored in backend item in one field only. Is there any other alternative you can suggest for achieving this functionality so that we can submit and show files in individual sections of the form?

Comment: Hi Adarsh. According to my research and testing, there is currently no better way to achieve your needs. In SharePoint Online only supports a single one Attachments control within the Edit form.